# User edited my question to fit his answer

Tags: discussion, support, answers, edits, editing-help

I wrote an HTML and JavaScript question, requesting an answer that worked with a certain type of input. A user posted an answer, and I told him in a comment that it didn't work for the type of input I asked for.
They went in, and edited my question to make it not say that it needed to be this specific type of input; thus making his answer valid for the changed (by them) question. Obviously looking for an upvote.

They changed **my question** to fit **their answer**. That's outrageous. I had to go in and roll it back.

How can I prevent this? How can Stack Overflow prevent this?

Is there a way to block him from editing my question again?

Comment: you can always roll back... if it gets into an edit war, you can flag it for moderator attention and they will lock it. In the meantime, since you rolled it back, the issue is fixed, the system works as intended.

Comment: I'd suspect you're asking about [this particular revision](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/32513612/3)? If not please clarify which one in your question please.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ WAIT WHAT? I sure hope not... because that revision didn't change anything...

Comment: @Patrice I may well being wrong. Asked the OP for clarification.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ looking into what the OP said on the question to the user who did the edit, I don't see which other question this could be... and if it REALLY is that question.... maybe a bit of an over reaction... but after a re-read, yeah there WAS a change from number to text that I missed

Comment: @Patrice Well, that was the only rollback done by the OP I could spot with a quick revision of their recent edit rollbacks :-P ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Fair enough :P. But yeah, at first glance I totally missed the fact he changes the input from number to text.... à

Comment: Since the user in question has about 200k rep, I doubt this was done out of desperation for upvotes.

Comment: @daedalus I noticed afterwards. didn't find the removed line problematic, and at first I didn't catch the change in the code (beyond the formatting). Which is why I corrected myself. I still think the reaction if the op is a bit intense, but there was indeed a change

Comment: @Patrice And I apparently missed your clarification of that, my bad.  I've deleted that comment; sorry for the notification.

Comment: As I mentioned in a comment there, I didn't edit it to fit my answer. I edited it because when I tried to run your code as originally written, it didn't exhibit the problem you described. My change seemed like a minor change unrelated to the point of the question, and it allowed the code to reproduce the symptoms.

Comment: I now know that the issue is browser-specific, which is why the behavior I saw was different from what you saw (I use Chrome, you apparently use Firefox). Sorry about that.

Comment: Side note: "Obviously looking for an upvote" for user with 200K reputation is not so obvious :)

Comment: You've *obviously* jumped to a conclusion. It's highly unlikely that a user of that rep is *obviously looking for an upvote*. It's also highly unlikely that the question was edited to fit the answer. I'd suspect that you've misunderstood both the edit and the answer, but as you've failed to link to the question in your post (and I'm not going to presume that the link provided by others is correct) I can't confirm my suspicions. I'd highly suggest, however, that before you make accusations of misconduct or misbehavior you think twice and not make assumptions as to motive you can't prove.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> How can I prevent this?

You cannot, but as mentioned you can always rollback to a previous revision of your question.

> How can Stack Overflow prevent this?

Regarding edits made by users below 2k reputation: These are sent to the edit review queue, and these need to be approved by a number of other users to agree it's a valid and helpful edit, that improves your question.

> Is there a way to block him from editing my question again?

No, not really if it was a +2k user. If you feel their behaviors are invalid, flag your question for moderator attention, and explain your issue clearly.